# Why is function fopen deprecated in MSVC from MSVC2005?

Tags: c, visual-c++, cl.exe

In ISO C, function `fopen` is used to open a file.

```
FILE *fp = fopen ("text.txt", "r");
```

But from MSVC2005, Microsoft mark this function deprecated. An MSVC-specific function `fopen_s` created by Microsoft is recommended in 2005 or higher version of MSVC.

```
FILE *fp = NULL;
fopen_s (&fp, "text.txt", "r");
```

The main difference between these two functions is the return value type. ISO C function `fopen` returns a pointer to the new  file stream if success, `NULL` if fail. However, the return value type of MSVC function `fopen_s` is `int`, which returns zero if success, non-zero integer if fail.

The question is: Why Microsoft mark the standard function `fopen` returning `FILE *` deprecated, recommending its own function `fopen_s` returning `int` from MSVC2005? (This question is about the reason why Microsoft does this, not how to disable the deprecation)

Comment: I believe it would fall under "Parameter Validation" and "Enhanced error reporting" as described here [Security Features in the CRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/security-features-in-the-crt?view=msvc-170)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/security-features-in-the-crt?view=msvc-170 `Enhanced error reporting. The secure functions return error codes with more error information than was available with the pre-existing functions. The secure functions and many of the pre-existing functions now set errno and often return an errno code type as well, to provide better error reporting.`

Comment: "Why Microsoft ... recommending its own (Enhanced error reporting) function" would be consistent  with [EEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Um, `fopen_s` is part of the C11 standard. See K.3.5.2.1. [It gets a brief mention on this blog](https://smartbear.com/blog/c11-a-new-c-standard-aiming-at-safer-programming/).

Comment: @RaymondChen `fopen_s()`, as part of annex K is optional.  It is not well support by compilers, nor does MS compiler support it as specified in the standard but opts for a variation in type for the size argument.  Movements exist to drop annex K in the next C, but that that is at best a _maybe_.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is function fopen deprecated in MSVC from MSVC2005?

Because Microsoft did some big analysis at the time regarding which functions that were often exploited or present in buggy programs. Then they did the wrong conclusion that those functions were the culprit and not the incompetent programmer who had written a program full of exploits and bugs. So they decided to get rid of the symptoms not the root cause by flagging various perfectly fine functions as obsolete.

It's fairly impossible to exploit `fopen` unless you pass unsanitized user input to it directly as parameter. Which is not fault of this function, the cause of that problem is the uneducated quack programmer who did such a stupid thing.

Rather than blacklisting a bunch of mostly fine functions, it would have been more meaningful to start educating programmers regarding how they should sanitize input, by using `fgets`, `memchr` and other such functions.

So mostly Microsoft were being confused, although in their defence, they did also start to perfectly sensibly warn against using some broken-by-design functions such as `gets` and `strncpy`.

---

> The main difference between these two functions is the return value type. ISO C function fopen returns a pointer to the new file stream if success, NULL if fail. However, the return value type of MSVC function fopen_s is int, which returns zero if success, non-zero integer if fail.

It would seem that the main difference is that the old, non-standard `fopen_s` returns an error upon receiving a null pointer parameter, which is an error check of very dubious value.

As far as I can tell, Microsoft's version is not compatible with the C11 bounds-checking interface with the same function present. The bounds-checking `fopen_s` comes with an `'u'` suffix option to the mode parameter, which I can't find mentioned in Microsoft's documentation.

Well, lets try if MSVC even implements the bounds-checking interface from C11, it's easy to do:

```c
#ifndef __STDC_LIB_EXT1__
  #error This compiler does not support fopen_s.
#endif
```

Result on the latest and greatest MSVC 19.32 from 2022 (compile with `/std:c17`):

> fatal error C1189: #error:  This compiler does not support fopen_s.

Hmm well that's probably for the best anyway since the bounds-checking interface has been heavily criticised, see for example this excellent paper [Field Experience With Annex K — Bounds Checking Interfaces](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm)

But well, just to be clear, lets see if we accidentally picked a non-C compiler by testing for compliance with ISO/IEC 9899:1990/AMD1:1995 or better:

```
#ifndef __STDC__
  #error This compiler was deprecated in 1995. Consider using gcc instead.
#endif
```

Result on the latest and greatest MSVC 19.32 from 2022 (compile with `/std:c17`):

> fatal error C1189: #error:  This compiler was deprecated in 1995. Consider using gcc instead.

Oh dear. I better start looking for a C compiler from 1996 or later.

Comment: The only function removed in C standard library is `gets`, because this function cannot do stuff like: `scanf ("%10[^\n]", str);` (use field width specifier for string) or `scanf ("%m[^\n]", &str);` (dynamically allocate sufficient memory for string)

Comment: @stanchcorder6 Yes but `strnlen` and a few others with similar, blatant design flaws should always be avoided in every C program.

Comment: `strncpy()` isn't actually broken by design. It's just something almost, but not quite entirely unlike what people want most of the time, being a fixed-length persistent record function instead of a string-function. Imho, it shouldn't have been put in the standard library for that reason.

Comment: @Deduplicator It wasn't originally designed for null terminated strings, but as it was included in the standard lib, they made it handle null termination although in a very poor way. Thus it is broken by design when used on null terminated strings. If it didn't handle null termination at all, then it would just be unsuitable and not plain broken.

Comment: @Lundin If you go that route to call it broken by design, you should also call a sports car a broken by design airplane. After all, it can only fly if driven off a cliff with sufficient speed, and hasn't the knack of missing the ground shortly after. One can substitute for the other in certain very limited circumstances, but it is a very poor idea as it hardly works and is supremely wasteful and cumbersome.

Comment: @Deduplicator The problem in this case was that they took a sports car and put wings on it with hot glue, then called it an airplane and placed it in the airplane hangar for all pilots to use (and crash). I'm not sure if the null termination handling was originally there when the function was used for fixed strings back in the dinosaur days, but I very much doubt it. Do you have any info claiming otherwise?

Comment: @Lundin What null termination handling? `strncpy()` copies the first up to n characters from source, stopping if the next would be null, and nulls out the rest of the destination. No termination involved.

Comment: @Deduplicator It stops when it encounters a null terminator, regardless of the `n` passed. I don't see how that would be correct behavior for those old fixed-width strings. As for why it fills up zeroes in the end, the C rationale claims that the only reason strncpy does that is because that ensured "efficient field-wise comparisons".

Comment: If you store a string into a fixed-width record, you don't need to store a terminator, but must zero the rest or leak information. Efficient field-wise comparison could also be the rationale of course.